# I don't get how from an array of Strings (parentRootItems), I do get objects with this code

Tags: objective-c

I don't get how from an array of Strings (parentRootItems), I do get objects with this code:

```
NSArray *parentRootItems = [pFolder rootItems];
NSLog(@"parentRootItems %@", [parentRootItems description]);

NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.%@", metadata.lookupItemsKeyPath];
NSLog(@"keyPath %@", keyPath);

NSArray *managedItems = [parentRootItems valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
NSLog(@"managedItems %@", [managedItems description]);
```

Thanks

Output

```
parentRootItems (Self-Inflicted Wounds / Rebirth)
                (Self-Inflicted Wounds / Rebirth)
                ...


keyPath @distinctUnionOfObjects.Series

 managedItems (
    <CBSeries: 0x1ddf3c0> (entity: Series; id: 0x1ddf260 <x-coredata://2B6F6719-9BCB-4C5C-B027-0DE2C7C1910C/Series/p350> ; data: {
    ClzID = 37268;
    Comics = "<relationship fault: 0x1de3790 'Comics'>";
    Complete = 0;
    DisplayName = Annihilators;
    Frequency = nil;
    ISSN = nil;
    Image = nil;
    Name = nil;
    NumIssues = 0;
    SortName = Annihilators;
    Stories = "<relationship fault: 0x1de39c0 'Stories'>";
    The = nil;
    URL = nil;
    UniqueID = 1;
}),
    <CBSeries: 0x1dd2940> (entity: Series; id: 0x1db4b60 <x-coredata://2B6F6719-9BCB-4C5C-B027-0DE2C7C1910C/Series/p354> ; data: {
    ClzID = 3856;
    Comics = "<relationship fault: 0x1de4230 'Comics'>";
    Complete = 0;
    DisplayName = Futurama;
    Frequency = nil;
    ISSN = nil;
    Image = nil;
    Name = nil;
    NumIssues = 0;
    SortName = Futurama;
    Stories = "<relationship fault: 0x1de4510 'Stories'>";
    The = nil;
    URL = nil;
    UniqueID = 9;
}),
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parentRootItems` isn't an array of strings. By the looks of this it is an array of managed objects, which each have a `.Series` attribute, which points to another managed object, of `Series` entity.

You are getting back an array containing each `Series` entity used by the objects in `parentRootItems`, with any duplicates removed.

To see more clearly what is in `parentRootItems`, use the following log message instead of the `description` which is what you are currently doing:

```
NSLog(@"Parent root items: %@",parentRootItems);
```